# caret: performing grouped regression with train()

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, r-caret

Hopefully this isn't a completely idiotic question. I have a dataset `df, n = 2228, p = 19` that describes characteristics of `5` breeds of horses. I would like to model the continuous variable `price` as a function of the other 17 predictor variables (even mix of categorical and continuous) for each `breed` by first splitting the data into `training` and `test`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
library(glmnet)
# pre- processing reveals no undo correlation, linear dependency or near
# zero variance veriables
train <- df %>% group_by(breed) %>% sample_frac(size = 2/3) %>% droplevels()
test <- anti_join(df, train) %>% droplevels()
# I imagine I should be somehow able to do this in the following step but can't
# figure it out
model <- train(price ~ ., data = train, method = "glmnet")
test$pred <- predict(model, newdata = test)
```

As far as I can tell I have no issue splitting the data by `breed` (see the above code). However, I can't figure out how to fit the model grouped by `breed`. What I would like to do is analogous to the following from the package `nlme` i.e. `lmList(price ~ . |breed, data = df)`

Comment: code looks reasonable to me, what's your question? check out `createDataPartition()` in caret it was designed  to handle the training/testing split

Comment: @NathanDay Sorry, clarified question

Comment: gotcha, I don't know how to do training on the fly for multiple group with caret. you could always use `split` and `lapply` to crank through it but I bet someone on here can offer a cleaner solution

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is something like

```
horse_typex <- df %>% filter(breed == typex)
```

for each type of horse, and then split these up into test and training sets.

If you desire to do a linear regression, perhaps you may want to model the log of the price instead, since it is likely skewed.

Comment: Thank you, will consider log transforming the `price` variable. As far as I can tell, I was able to satisfactorily split the dataset into training and test. I clarified the question. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: If you want to fit the model by breed, then you need a different data set for each one. Unless you want to use breed as a categorical variable and have many interactions so that each variable behaves differently for each breed. Get it?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
models <- dlply(df, "breed", function(d_breed) 
  train(price ~ ., data = d_breed, method = "glmnet"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying to use `purrr`

```
library(purrr)

models <- train %>% 
            split(.$breed) %>% 
            map(~train(.$price ~ ., data = ., method = "glmnet"))
```

or with `dplyr`

```
models <- train %>% 
            group_by(breed) %>% 
            do(train(price ~ ., data = ., method = "glmnet"))
```

It is difficult to know if this will work, but it is worth a try.